# Почему ajax срабатывает сразу два раза?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

У меня есть php скрипт:

```html
echo "<td>
<select id='ocenka-day".$chislo."-" . $rowstudentlist['id'] . "'>
<option disabled selected></option>
<option value='0'>Н</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
</select>
<script type='text/javascript' >
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#ocenka-day".$chislo."-".$rowstudentlist['id']."').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
         var vstudiin = '".$rowstudentlist['iin']."';
         var vday = ".$chislo.";
         var vprepodiin = '".$iin."';
         var vdisid = $selectdis;
         var vmonth = $selectmonth;
         var vgr = $selectgr;
         var vsemestr = $semestr;
      $.ajax({type:'POST',
      url:'my-journals-save.php',
      data:{ocenka:value,day:vday,studiin:vstudiin,prepodiin:vprepodiin,disid:vdisid,month:vmonth,gr:vgr,semestr:vsemestr},
      dataType:'html',
      success:function(){
            }
      });});});
  </script>
</td>";
```

Второй скрип для вставки в таблицу (my-journals-save.php):

```
$studiin=$_POST['studiin'];
    $ocenka=$_POST['ocenka'];
    $day=$_POST['day'];
....
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect.php');

$sql = pg_query($dbconn,"INSERT INTO journal (disid,disname,monthnumber,monthname,semestr,prepodiin,studiin,gr,day,ocenka,ugods,ugodp,ocenkadat)
VALUES ($disid,'$disname',$month,'$monthname',$semestr,'$prepodiin','$studiin','$gr',$day,$ocenka,$ugods,$ugodp,'$dat')");
```

Всё бы хорошо но в базу данных при вставке ставится сразу два раза,как я понял скрипт срабатывает два раза. даже по секундам одинаковый, только ID разные
Скрипт вешается только один раз, скрипт не дублируется,  ID элементов тоже 
похожие вопросы в stackoverflow прочитал:)

Comment: вы без записи в бд проверили бы сколько объектов приходит, так можно понять где все таки два раза срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему 
добавлением .unbind('change'); 
перед событием on.('change'...

Answer (score 0):

Может в данном случае unbind срабатывает, но было бы логично использовать pg_close() в конце запроса.